# How to adjust the arrow/caret on a DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've created a DropdownButton to my app but I can't seem to find a way to adjust the position of the caret/arrow at the right side of the control.  It's not centered vertically with the selection.

```
  Container(
color: Colors.white,
child: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        canvasColor: Colors.white
    ),
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 15.0),
        child:
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
                elevation: 0,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    letterSpacing: 1.5
                ),
                value: vm.selectedCasino,
                onChanged: (Casino result) {
                  vm.onSelectCasino(result);
                  menuController.close();
                },
                items: allCasinos.map((Casino casino){
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Casino>(
                    value: casino,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                            child: Image.asset(Util.colorLogoPath(casino), width: 60.0,)
                        ),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                            child: Text(casino.name.toUpperCase())
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList()
            )
        )
    )
),
```

)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Seems to be not possible at the moment. You can report a bug in the flutter repo/ issues. As a workaround, I'd put the `DropdownButton` and a new widget `Image` for the arrow in a `Stack` and align them that way.